# How to resolve NumberFormatException: Empty string?

Tags: java, validation, numberformatexception

When I run this program i get the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String.  Is it possible to make this work by throwing the exception some how or must I use a try catch statement?

```
private double[] scores3 = new double[5]; 
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public void enterData() 
{
   double score;
   double numberMin = 0;
   double numberMax = 100;



do{
    System.out.println("Enter the student's third test score");

      while (!keyboard.hasNextDouble()) {

      keyboard.next();
      }
       score3 = keyboard.nextDouble();


        }
         while  (score3 <= numberMin || score3 >= numberMax);
         double score3 = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
```

Comment: If you throw the exception, it still must be caught and handled *somewhere*. Just use a try/catch block.

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in your debugger as it isn't doing what you think it is doing.  The Exception is symptom of a confused program, you are better off fixing the cause.

Comment: What is keyboard exactly?

Comment: I'm wondering why you parse `keyboard.nextLine()` and not `score3`? As far as I can tell, the error you got is there.

Comment: You can also use Apache commons StringUtils to check if a string is numeric prior to converting.

Comment: Can you explain why you have used this line     double score3 = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());

Answer (score 1):

Before parsing a String to a Number.. compare the string with " " or use `isEmpty()` function to check if its a empty string or not !

Example:

```
if (myString.isEmpty()) {
    //Do Nothing
} else {
    //Code to perform calculations
}
```

or

```
if (!myString.isEmpty()) {
    //Code to perform calculations
}
```

Comment: This would break for every non-numeric String that doesn't equal `" "`.

Comment: Should be `myString.trım().isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0):

To your question of if you can throw the error elsewhere, you could do that by declaring

```
public void enterData() throws NumberFormatException
```

However I would recommend using a try catch block if you want to continue iterating over your while statements.

Comment: But if he throws it, he still must handle the thrown exception wherever he calls the method that is throwing it, and thus will need a try/catch block.